# Automate to click 'down' key and take screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

I am newbie who wants to learn python. English is not my primary language, please ignore grammer error.

Here's my question.
In tradingview charts, i want to take screenshot, click down button, take screenshot again, wait for 3 second then go to next stock.

As i am newbie on python as well as stackoverflow if my any action fell dumb or wrong then please give me guidence.

Answer (score 1):

### Keyboard module (python) to control keyboard

**first we need install a module name- keyboard in python**

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

**First, let's import the module:**

```
import keyboard
```

**Next, you can also simulate key presses using the send() function:**

it will press space:

```
keyboard.send("space")
```

**This will press and release the space button. In fact, there is an equivalent function press_and_release() that does the same thing.**

---

**You can also pass multi-keys:**

```
keyboard.send("windows+d")
```

**The + operator means we press both buttons in the same time, you can also use multi-step hotkeys:**

send ALT+F4 in the same time, and then send space,

```
keyboard.send("alt+F4, space")
```

**But what if you want to press a specific key but you don't want to release it ? Well, press() and release() functions comes into play:**

press CTRL button

```
keyboard.press("ctrl")
```

release the CTRL button

```
keyboard.release("ctrl")
```

**So this will press CTRL button and then release it, you can do anything in between, such as sleeping for few seconds, etc.**

---

**But now what if you want to write a long text and not just specific buttons ? send() would be inefficient. Luckily for us, write() function does exactly that, it sends artificial keyboard events to the OS simulating the typing of a given text, let's try it out:**

```
keyboard.write("Python Programming is always fun!", delay=0.1)
```

Setting delay to 0.1 indicates 0.1 seconds to wait between keypresses, this will look fancy like in hacking movies!

### Saving your problem

**note- in windows 10, hot key for tacking screen shot is "windows+PrtScn.
Use your own hot key**

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\webcontrol\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("url ypu want to reach")

keyboard.send("windows+PrtScn")

keyboard.send("down")

keyboard.send("windows+PrtScn")

time.sleep(3)

driver.get("next stock url you want")
```

**note- for going to next stock you can also use buttons or you can use selenium to click that particular stock**

### THANKS!

Comment: any way to loop this and add delay in every loop? or add presses with time delay like pyautogui
"keyboard.send("window+printscreen, down"